# Call REST API at repeated intervals until no records found

Tags: spring-boot, rest, cron, software-design

I have a scenario where I need to process around 1,00,000 transactions. At once, the API can handle and process 5000 transactions.

What mechanism can I incorporate to call the API at repeated intervals until all the 1,00,000 records get processed?

I was thinking of Spring boot cron but didn't find a way to stop the cron when all transactions are processed.